# Disabling a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application I have a form called person . I wanted to disable a field date_of_death when the is_alive checkbox is selected

`<%= f.input :is_alive, as: :boolean %>
<%= f.input :date_of_death, as: :datetime, include_blank: true %>`

The jquery code i have tried:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#person_is_alive").click(function() {
        var isDisabled = $("#person_is_alive").prop('checked')
        if(isDisabled) {
            $("person_date_of_death").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#person_date_of_death").prop('disabled', true)
        }
    });
});
```

I have reffered the id which i have used by viewing the page source from the browser.

Comment: You haven't asked a question, you've just dumped requirements on us. This is a JavaScript problem, it has very little to do with Rails. What have you tried so far? Show us your attempted solution.

Comment: Sign me up. I want to avoid that thing called death, too.

Comment: I have added the jquery code which i have used but i doesn't work for me .  @meagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the '#' in front of your ID selector.

`$("person_date_of_death").removeAttr("disabled");`

should be:

`$("#person_date_of_death").removeAttr("disabled");`